# Count data distinct sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the problem when i want to count data in distinct my postgresql

Below is my query.

```
SELECT COUNT (distinct on (a.userid) a.userid, b.name, a.checktime
FROM checkinout a 
LEFT JOIN userinfo b
       ON b.userid = a.userid
WHERE a.checktime >= '2017-12-28 06:15:00' 
AND a.checktime <= '2017-12-28 07:45:00')
```

And i am getting syntax error  **at or near "on"**.

Comment: just  select `count(distinct a.userid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
select COUNT(distinct co.userid)
from checkinout co left join
     userinfo ui
     on ui.userid = co.userid
where ui.checktime >= '2017-12-28 06:15:00' and
      ui.checktime <= '2017-12-28 07:45:00';
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is being turned into an inner join by the `WHERE`, so you might as well do:

```
select COUNT(distinct co.userid)
from checkinout co join
     userinfo ui
     on ui.userid = co.userid
where ui.checktime >= '2017-12-28 06:15:00' and
      ui.checktime <= '2017-12-28 07:45:00';
```